# how to connect Apache Lucene with Node JS?

Tags: node.js, solr, lucene

I have to develop an application which will have angular JS as UI, Node JS as backend. It will have text search facility for which I am doing some research. I need to know how to connect Apache Lucene with Node JS? Or should I consider Solr?

Comment: Use Solr or Elasticsearch. There are multiple clients for both available for Node.

Comment: If still I want to go for lucene then may I have any suggestion?

Comment: There [are modules](https://github.com/tjgillies/node-lucene) that [wrap clucene](https://github.com/amcjen/node-clucene).